# React OnClick and html button not working on smaller screen size

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a responsive button that works on larger screens, however once the screen is reduced to the size of a mobile phone at a particular size, the button stops working completely and can't be redirected to another page.

HTML is below

```
<div className="col-md-2">
    <button type="submit" onClick={redirect} className="profile-edit-btn">Edit Profile</button>
</div>
```

The redirect function is:

```
function redirect() {
    props.history.push("/update/" + user._id);
  }
```

On a large screen the button is like this:

[image]

On a small screen it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Could you put your images for larger screen and mobile screen?

Comment: When in mobile screen, the click only not working for redirecting or even not go to redirect()?

Comment: Hey @Phillip the images work, and the redirect isn't working at all, the function isn't being called at all.

Comment: I mean images for showing us on this post. I want to see how button changes on different layouts.

Comment: oh ok, i just updated the question with some images. @Phillip